# undefined method `mask' when when using ipaddr library

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the method mask in my script, but I'm getting this error

```
  undefined method `mask' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Even though I have added this line on the top of my file

```
        require 'ipaddr'
```

I'm using the method somewhere in my code like

```
         x = mask(maximum)
```

Maximum is an integer.

I'm using Ruby 2.2.0 and I checked the documentation it says the library is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new ipaddr object, then use `mask` method.

```
require 'ipaddr'
ipaddr1 = IPAddr.new
x = ipaddr1.mask(maximum)
```